# Passing url from JS to MVC Controller in a form of a string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

So I am passing a string URL from my JS file, which is something like

> "https://....."

like this

```
$http.post("user", vm.user)
       .then(function (response) {
           $http.get("user/url/" + response.data.url)
                   .then.....
```

Now this is where I am having problems,

my controller gets this URL but it drops the second forward slash,

so it ends up being

> "https:/....."

my controller looks like this,

```
[HttpGet("user/url/{*Url}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string Url)
    {
        try
        {
```

anyway to get past this ? how do I make sure the string is intact when it is passed back ?

Comment: can you share your sample code for better explanation.

Comment: How do you pass ?  via AJAX ?

Comment: Did you try adding a slash before `user/url` as `/user/url` ?

Comment: I am getting the url back from a different controller, which is correct all the way back to the JS file, its only when I use the response to pass it back to another controller where it is dropping the /, I was hoping to just be able to pass it and not do anything to it